# i want to do Maxzero function in Python

Tags: python, list

Return a version of the given array where each zero value in the array is replaced by the largest odd value to the right of the zero in the array. If there is no odd value to the right of the zero, leave the zero as a zero.
This question was originally made for java but i would like to do it in python still i cant solve it.
kindly help me

zeroMax([0, 5, 0, 3])→[5, 5, 3, 3]

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def odd_right(a):
    return [i for i in a if i%2 != 0]

def zeroMax(l):
    for i, v in enumerate(l[:]):
        if v == 0:
            temp_list = odd_right(l[i:])
            rep = max(temp_list) if temp_list else 0 
            l[i] = rep
    return l
```

Although stackoverflow, I feel is not the right place for coding questions like this.